# Como saber se comando do script foi executado com sucesso?

Tags: bash, shell

Preciso que o script identifique se o arquivo tar.gz foi gerado com sucesso em um if. Segue um exemplo não funcional:

```
VAR=tar -zcf teste.tar.gz teste/testeDir
if [VAR]
then
echo "Sucesso"
else
echo "Erro"
fi
```

Bem simples eu acho mas não consegui fazer! Aguardo respostas...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a váriável $?
ela retorna "0" se o ultimo comando foi executado com sucesso, e retorna "1" se houve erro neste comando.

Abaixo segue uma tabela com essas variáveis especiais que estão disponíveis no shell:

Variável    Descrição

- $0    Parâmetro número 0 (nome do comando ou função)
- $1    Parâmetro número 1 (da linha de comando ou função)
- ...   Parâmetro número N da linha de comando ou função)
- $9    Parâmetro número 9 (da linha de comando ou função)
- ${10} Parâmetro número 10 (da linha de comando ou função)
- $#    Número total de parâmetros da linha de comando ou função
- $*    Todos os parâmetros, como uma string única
- $@    Todos os parâmetros, como várias strings protegidas
- $$    PID do processo atual (do próprio script)
- $!    PID do último processo em segundo plano
- $_    Último argumento do último comando executado
- $?    Valor de retorno do último comando executado

veja este exemplo do comando cat em meu terminal:

```
felix@asgard:[~]: cat escrever.py 
arq = open('arquivo.txt','w')
arq.write("Pyhton é legal")
arq.close()
felix@asgard:[~]: echo $?
0
felix@asgard:[~]: cat escreve.py 
cat: escreve.py: No such file or directory
felix@asgard:[~]: echo $?
1
```

No exemplo abaixo só coloquei o resultado de "sucesso" porque em meus testes, quando tentei compactar um arquivo inexistente ou mesmo colocando argumentos errados para compactar, simplesmente o comando não era executado, 'quebrando' assim o script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tar -zcf escrever.tar.gz escrever.py

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "sucesso"
fi
```

Comment: muito bom, resolveu meu problema, vlw!

Comment: +1 Sua resposta tá legal, mas se puser um exemplo tipo `tar -zcf teste.tar.gz teste/testeDir` `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` etc, aplicado ao comando da pergunta, para que outros usuários aprendam como fica na pratica, fica mais legal ainda